# Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF7405C1068 в Проект1.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero

Tags: c++, c, математика, visual-c++, ряды

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, n;
    float s;
    s = 1,5;
    n = 2;

    cout << "vvedite a:";
    cin >> a;

    while (a >= s) {
        n++;
        s += 1 / n;
    }

    cout << "naim n=" << n;

    return 0;
}
```

в 14 строке (s += 1 / n;) происходит деление на ноль, но я понятия не имею откуда он взялся о:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF7405C1068 в Проект1.exe:
>   0xC0000094: Integer division by zero.

Comment: n++ при переходе через границу разрядной сетки даст в итоге 0. 100%. Добавьте условие `if (n != 0)` ... но тогда уже получите "зацикливание". У вас скорее всего безконечный цикл (т.к. a=0)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не содержит какой-то конкретной проблемы, вместо этого здесь ворох разнородных проблем, вызванных незнанием автором языка. В связи с этим, данный вопрос не будет полезен другим посетителям сайта.

Answer (score 8):

Самая глупая ошибка у вас в `s = 1,5;` - в C++ нужно использовать **точку**, а не запятую.

Вторая по глупости ошибка в том, что вы используете целочисленное деление

```
s += 1 / n;
```

которое всегда дает (при `n > 1`) нуль. Так что программа зациклится, `n` перевалит за границу допустимого и станет 0.

Но и это еще не все. Все равно ваш метод расчетов для `int n` не может дать значение выше примерно 22.064778 - это все, что вы можете получить (при `n` достигающем максимального представимого этим типом значения).

[Гармонический ряд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4) - **ОЧЕНЬ** медленно расходящийся ряд (для того, чтобы сумма превысила 100, необходимо около 10<sup>43</sup> элементов ряда). Да, эта сумма станет заведомо больше любого значения... но при таких `n`, что вашей жизни (а то и жизни вселенной) не хватит, чтоб этого дождаться. Ну, и точности компьютера тоже не хватит :)

Эта задача решается не так - по крайней мере для достаточно больших `n`.

Comment: Соглашусь, Гармонический ряд хоть и медленно, но расходящийся. Сумма равна бесконечности.